# Alternative api of strerror_r for windows OS

Tags: c++, c, winapi, visual-c++, boost

I see [strerror_r](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/strerror.3.asp)(...) API is no longer supported in visual C++ 2008, probably because of issue with thread safety. I want to use similar functionality in my program. 
Is there any other winapi which does the same thing as strerror_r(..)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try [strerror_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51sah927%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). It appears to be thread safe.

Note that the parameter order of strerror_s is different from strerror_r. If writing portable code you might want to use a define

```
#define strerror_r(errno,buf,len) strerror_s(buf,len,errno)
```

Comment: not sure, if its thread safe. Though, this is an alternative for what i wanted so thanks for your ans..

Comment: Link to strerror_s is a "retired document." Seems to be part of C11 now : https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror

Comment: Important note when calling strerror_s when compiling with MVSC:
Quote from linked cppreference:
As with all bounds-checked functions, strerror_s and strerrorlen_s are only guaranteed to be available if __STDC_LIB_EXT1__ is defined by the implementation and if the user defines __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ to the integer constant 1 before including <string.h>.

Answer (score 0):

> I see strerror_r(...) API is no longer supported in visual C++ 2008, probably because of issue with thread safety

I'm not persuaded that it was ever supported.  That link goes to documentation for the MKS Toolkit rather than Visual C++ 2008.  The strerror_r function exists to be a thread-safe strerror.  Microsoft's URLs have a tendency to rust quickly but, today, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strerror-strerror-wcserror-wcserror?view=vs-2019 implies that vanilla strerror is thread-safe on Windows, with:

> All of these functions return a pointer to an error-message string, in a thread-local storage buffer owned by the runtime. Later calls on the same thread can overwrite this string.

So there's no need to use strerror_r on Windows.